# Can't download images from google drive through node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I am working on **node.js** and trying to access google drive and I can access the google drive images but I'm not able to download the images.
now i pasted the entire code. API returns the images we can log the names and file id. from there i trying to download that images.

```
      fs.createWriteStream(file.name);
```

i used this piece of code. but that downloaded image file format was not supported

logs in consloe:

File Name :  resume
File ID :  1wGthzSGg6axSL4unlz1tiVjzhRUPRCXA
File Name :  Remisha Resume.docx
File ID :  0BwgraHo4GmEXYUdvcFBQa2pjVlQ3dE9TWDB0a0VSOS1RRTZR
File Name :  IMG20181125154740.jpg
File ID :  1zGKGka51EnDuIl4wNqL5GogFNYZpzy_O
File Name :  IMG20181125185027.jpg
File ID :  1l5s2yR_5YMJcjFUQjkVFBC0f5PD0WSzw
File Name :  IMG20181125185037.jpg
File ID :  1vOxliIoztqUD_BbnjdXMBd9rpVTR4mvt
File Name :  IMG20181125155437.jpg
File ID :  10QXoAIjVvval0Xnlswf0bZmFYD2fqOK1
File Name :  IMG20181125185039.jpg
File ID :  1lcfUQJ--gnxxizqUHojKp2cX_RNpUx9c
File Name :  IMG20181125160713.jpg
File ID :  1bOpfM04Fo0fvY2Base8dSTRDkjesPz1i
File Name :  IMG20181125185043.jpg
File ID :  1Yk09Fe7nye3NwvYQNVDNSghozxiIFOtI
File Name :  IMG20181125165932.jpg
File ID :  1pe5vZFdmDBX0PSSllW2C2cLmYchAnS8G

saved images in disk is not supported format

```
 const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  var drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 4,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {


      **files.map((file) => {
      //i am trying to download the image here. but that downloaded image
      // file format was not supported 
      fs.createWriteStream(file.name)
        //console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
      });**


    } else {
      console.log('No files found.');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you share the logs when you run the code?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot thanks for your response.
logs in console:
File Name :  resume
File ID :  1wGthzSGg6axSL4unlz1tiVjzhRUPRCXA
File Name :  Remisha Resume.docx
File ID :  0BwgraHo4GmEXYUdvcFBQa2pjVlQ3dE9TWDB0a0VSOS1RRTZR
File Name :  IMG20181125154740.jpg
File ID :  1zGKGka51EnDuIl4wNqL5GogFNYZpzy_O
File Name :  IMG20181125185027.jpg
File ID :  1l5s2yR_5YMJcjFUQjkVFBC0f5PD0WSzw
File Name :  IMG20181125185037.jpg